# Css center justifying a display:flex navbar

Tags: html, css

**How do I center-justify the navbar?**

I think that the problem is with the `display: flex`. I have tried:

```css
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
```

on the `ul` tag. This doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to bypass the `display: flex` associated problems?

I have margins and padding set to 0. Also, is there a way if I could set my whole website between 300px margins?

Source code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Black Han Sans', sans-serif;
}

.menu-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-1 ul {
  width: 800px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border: 0.5px solid #000000;
}

.menu-1 ul li {
  width: 150px;
  flex: 1;
  border-left: 0.5px solid #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Jua', sans-serif;
}

.menu-1 ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.menu-1 ul li:hover a {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 0.5px solid black;
}

.menu-1 ul li:active a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en, ko'>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans&display=swap&subset=korean" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jua&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <br>

  <div class="headings">
    <h1>
      <img src="logo_refined2.jpg" alt="Logo_Img" width="80" height="45">
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color:black;">간장공장</a>
    </h1>
  </div>


  <nav class="menu-1">
    <ul>
      <li style="border-left:0.5px solid #e9e9e9;"><a href="#">커뮤니티</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">식단</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">갤러리</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">마켓</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `I could set my whole website between 300px margins`????

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` was fine (not `inline-block`) , then you give `800px` `width` to `ul` , you may remove it since you also give a `width` to `li` + `flex:1;` (width is then like `min-width`, `flex:1` tell it to grow to fill ul).

this below  seems to be what you try to do :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Black Han Sans', sans-serif;
}

.menu-1 {
  display:flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-1 ul { 
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border: 0.5px solid #000000;
}

.menu-1 ul li {
  width: 150px;
  flex: 1;
  border-left: 0.5px solid #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Jua', sans-serif;
}

.menu-1 ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.menu-1 ul li:hover a {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 0.5px solid black;
}

.menu-1 ul li:active a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en, ko'>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans&display=swap&subset=korean" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jua&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <br>

  <div class="headings">
    <h1>
      <img src="logo_refined2.jpg" alt="Logo_Img" width="80" height="45">
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color:black;">간장공장</a>
    </h1>
  </div>


  <nav class="menu-1">
    <ul>
      <li style="border-left:0.5px solid #e9e9e9;"><a href="#">커뮤니티</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">식단</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">갤러리</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">마켓</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</body>

</html>
```